# Determine the correct /dev/usb/lp*

Tags: usb, printing

is there a way to determine which printer uses which `/dev/usb/lp*`? I'm building a system which should automatically allocate printers if reconnected. And I don't want to force assignment using `udev` rules. I can find the required device on the bus, but can't find it's `/dev/usb/lp*`.

Answer (score 1):

May be not the cleanest way but it works.
Replace "Brother Industries, Ltd" by your printer (look in lsusb)

```
    #!/bin/bash
    ID=$(lsusb |grep "Brother Industries, Ltd"|cut -d " " -f 6)
    vid=$(echo $ID|cut -d ":" -f 1)
    pid=$(echo $ID|cut -d ":" -f 2)
    msg="vid 0x$vid pid 0x$pid"
    echo "/dev/usb/$(dmesg |grep -i "$msg" |tail -n 1 |cut -d " " -f 2|cut -c 4-6)"
```